# Jenkins: difference between step and steps

Tags: jenkins

What's the difference between `step` as mentioned here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#step-general-build-step

and `steps` as mentioned here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/

Answer (score 2):

`steps` is a grouping of things to do inside a `stage`. Each instruction inside the `steps` is a `step`.

Here is an example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
     stages {
         stage('FirstStage') {
             steps { 
                 echo 'Hello World'       // step
                 echo 'Hello World again' // another step
             }
         stage('SecondStage') {
             steps { 
                 echo 'Hello World'       // yet another step
                 echo 'Hello World again' // another step again
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

step in "general-build-step"  is a general term，just like do some tasks in jenkins.

steps in https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/ is a specific usage of "steps".

So in my view, sorry,i think it's meaningless to found out the difference of them.